# Menu won't increase in height

Tags: css

I have a navigation menu on [this site](https://onmoneyline.com/) which looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to increase the height of the navigation for example to `60px`. I've tried playing with CSS to increase the height but the height won't change. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried height, padding, heigth !important but there's no effect on my menu.

Can you help me to increase the height of my navigation?

Comment: Please review [ask] and update your question to include a [mcve]. Otherwise, this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic) and should be closed as such.

Comment: Let me check. I'll post you the correct answer in a some minutes.

Comment: @zzzzBov I've edited the question. Please remove the on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my answer. The problem is the background for your navigation. I would prefer a solution like this:

```css
.row .nav {
    line-height: 60px;
    background: black;
}

.row .menu a {
  line-height: 60px;
}

.row .menu .sub-menu {
  top: 56px;
}
```

Insert this into your CSS. This code is tested and works. Tell me if it works for you.

It should looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that did it, thank you. I spent a few hours trying to make the menu look how I want it to look. Eh, didn't achieve it exactly, but good enough I guess. Thanks man :)

Comment: @Overloard Great :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
.row .sixteen.columns {
  height: 50px
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've never tried that out because it won't work